# What is the best way to implement a parametric function?

Tags: python, function, functional-programming, closures

Since Python believes *There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.* I wonder if there is a best way to use parametric functions in Python.

I came across with two approaches, either using a closure or `functools.partial`, as below,

```
def par_fun1(x, y):
    def par_fun_inner(p):
        return (x + y + p) ** 2
    return par_fun_inner

temp1 = par_fun1(2, 2)
temp1(1)
```

---

```
from functools import partial
def par_fun2(x, y, p):
    return (x + y + p) ** 2

temp2 = partial(par_fun2, 2, 2)
temp2(1)
```

---

Is anyone better than the other? Of course, if there are even better ways to implement parametric functions, please share your idea!

Comment: What do you think "parametric function" means? The Google results don't seem related to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am not sure about the jargon. But let me give an example, sometimes you want to pass a function to an optimization program to estimate its parameters, but besides parameters, this function also has other components/inputs to be passed into. Anyway, I wonder what's your suggestion to better the question?@user2357112

Comment: Either way works fine. It's not a big deal. There's also the option of using `lambda` instead of `partial`, although that can cause surprises if the lambda is still in use when the variables it's using take new values.